# Converting a plot with legends from version 9 to version 12

Tags: plotting, legending, compatibility

```
makeLegend[plotMark_, sizex_, sizey_, position_] := 

 Module[{graphics = {}}, 

  graphics = {Graphics[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ plotMark;

  Return[{graphics, LegendSize -> {sizex, sizey}, 

    LegendPosition -> position, LegendShadow -> None, 

    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times"}}] ]
```

Hi Guys!
Above is a part of a program which is initiated to use `` PlotLegends`​ `` package. It is now built-in function as of Mathematica 9.

My question is how can I make compatible the following commands

```
LegendSize
LegendPosition
LegendShadow
```

to work in Mathematica 12?

Comment: Have you already looked at the help file for `PlotLegends`?

Comment: Hi, I couldn't have managed which command is compatible for size, position and shadow in PlotLegends.